# Feature engineering using Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, feature-extraction

I have a pandas data-set in which one of the column is like this:

```
         Genre
        ------------
         Documentary
         Documentary
         Comedy|Mystery|Thriller
         Animation|Comedy|Family
         Documentary
         Documentary|Family
         Action|Adventure|Fantasy|Sci-Fi
         Crime|Drama|Mystery
         Action|Crime|Mystery|Thriller
```

How can I create multiple columns with each genre name and fill 1 if its contains that genre or else 0?

Expected Output: Pandas Dataframe

```
  Documentary  Comedy  Mystery  Thriller  Animation  Family  ......
    1           0       0          0        0          0
    1            0       0          0        0          0
    0            1        1         1        0          0
```

so on.

I tried using first converting it to list then split it, but it's not pythonic way to do it.

Can we do it efficiently using `apply` function or some other efficient techniques?

Comment: `get_dummies`? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Series.explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) + [pd.get_dummies](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html):

```
s_explode=df['Genre'].str.split('|').explode()
dfc=pd.get_dummies(s_explode).groupby(level=0).sum()
new_df=pd.concat([df['Genre'],dfc],axis=1)
print(new_df)
```

---

```
                              Genre  Action  Adventure  Animation  Comedy  \
0                      Documentary       0          0          0       0   
1                      Documentary       0          0          0       0   
2          Comedy|Mystery|Thriller       0          0          0       1   
3          Animation|Comedy|Family       0          0          1       1   
4                      Documentary       0          0          0       0   
5               Documentary|Family       0          0          0       0   
6  Action|Adventure|Fantasy|Sci-Fi       1          1          0       0   
7              Crime|Drama|Mystery       0          0          0       0   
8    Action|Crime|Mystery|Thriller       1          0          0       0   

   Crime  Documentary  Drama  Family  Fantasy  Mystery  Sci-Fi  Thriller  
0      0            1      0       0        0        0       0         0  
1      0            1      0       0        0        0       0         0  
2      0            0      0       0        0        1       0         1  
3      0            0      0       1        0        0       0         0  
4      0            1      0       0        0        0       0         0  
5      0            1      0       1        0        0       0         0  
6      0            0      0       0        1        0       1         0  
7      1            0      1       0        0        1       0         0  
8      1            0      0       0        0        1       0         1
```

Comment: Great. Is there any book/reference or website which contains depth knowledge of pandas and numpy for data frame. Thanks in advance.

Comment: data['genres'].str.split('|').explode() giving the error as :AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'explode'

Comment: you need version pandas 0.25.1

Answer (score 0):

It is straight simple with `str.get_dummies`

```
df1 = df.Genre.str.get_dummies('|')

Out[385]:
   Action  Adventure  Animation  Comedy  Crime  Documentary  Drama  Family  \
0       0          0          0       0      0            1      0       0
1       0          0          0       0      0            1      0       0
2       0          0          0       1      0            0      0       0
3       0          0          1       1      0            0      0       1
4       0          0          0       0      0            1      0       0
5       0          0          0       0      0            1      0       1
6       1          1          0       0      0            0      0       0
7       0          0          0       0      1            0      1       0
8       1          0          0       0      1            0      0       0

   Fantasy  Mystery  Sci-Fi  Thriller
0        0        0       0         0
1        0        0       0         0
2        0        1       0         1
3        0        0       0         0
4        0        0       0         0
5        0        0       0         0
6        1        0       1         0
7        0        1       0         0
8        0        1       0         1
```